# Grief with Extremely Simple Code

Tags: c++, while-loop, cin

The problem I am having could possibly be something with codeblocks, but I just want to double check and see if anyone sees a problem with my code.  I already think it has something to do with the while loop.  I keep getting a "Main.exe has stopped working" error.  I, personally, have a lot of difficulty choosing between options, so I'm trying to make a quick and dirty C++ program to choose a random option between a few given options.  Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

cout << "Enter Options to choose between." << endl << endl;

int i;
string option;

do {

    cin >> option[i];

    i++;
}
 while (cin != "done");

cout << option[ rand() %i ];

}
```

Comment: In your mind, what is `option[i]`?

Comment: Well `cin >> option[i]` is wrong since the string is empty and `i` is uninitizlized. What _exactly_ are you trying to do?

Comment: `i` is uninitialized and therefore essentially a random, probably very large value. `option` is just a single `string` and is initially empty. `option[i]` is the *ith* character of `option`, its type is `char`. `cin >> option[i]` therefore reads a single character and attempts to store it in an arbitrary position in an empty string (hence the crash; trying to write to some strange location in memory). This probably isn't what you want to do. Your code should reflect what you are actually trying to do. Computers follow your instructions relatively precisely. Code what you mean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program (with embedded comments) should do what you want.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
```

I used an explicit list of the names I want to import from the `std` namespace, since I cannot know what other names are defined there (there are probably more than 1000), and I really only need these few.

```
int main()
{
  std::srand(std::time(NULL));
```

The above statement initializes the random number generator, so you don’t get the same “random” number in every run of the program.

```
  cout << "Enter options to choose between, an empty line to finish:\n";
```

I changed your `"done"` into an empty string, since that is easier to type. Additionally, `std::endl` is not needed here. You should rather write `"\n"`, which is shorter and in most cases equivalent.

```
  vector<string> options;
```

These are all the options that have been entered so far. Each option is a `string`, and a `vector` can hold many elements, so these are many strings.

```
  for (string option; std::getline(cin, option) && option != ""; ) {
    options.push_back(option);
  }
```

This code reads the options. The variable `option` is only used for reading the options. After that, it is no longer needed. The `for` loop automatically limits the scope of the `option` variable, so that it can only be used in the `for` loop.

I also changed `cin >> option` into `getline(cin, option)` to allow for options that contain whitespace.

```
  cout << "You entered the following options:\n";
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < options.size(); i++) {
    cout << "* " << options[i] << "\n";
  }

  cout << "Your random option is " << options[std::rand() % options.size()] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: You can make the code much cleaner by replacing the while loop with a for loop. this allows you to give the string a scope without another layer of indentation. It also clearly states intent that option shouldn't be used outside the scope.

Comment: Nice Roland.  That worked perfectly.  I think I'll try to enclose the whole thing in a loop (if I can do that without breaking it).  Thanks to all for the replies.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading in strings with each cin, not characters, so your string is not what you want to use.

```
std::vector<std::string> options;
...
    string in;
    cin >> in;
    options.push_back(in);
```

So here use a vector of strings instead of a single string, then fill it with strings.